# create a cluster in clickhouse databse

Tags: database, cluster-computing, olap, clickhouse, yandex

I'm trying to create a cluster in yandex clickhouse, I don't know to do that.
I installed clickhouse in my local machine . I updated my config file, by reading the official documentation. But it is not clear for me. So help me to create a cluster in clickhouse.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from your question what you want to do. Which kind of cluster do you mean? Which hardware do you have?

I recommend you to read documentation pages about [replication](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/table_engines/replication/) and [distributed tables](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/table_engines/distributed/). Also this [tutorial](https://clickhouse.yandex/tutorial.html) maybe helpful.